# Team Foundation Server, Project Server on same server or separate?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, ms-project

Our company is looking to do new installs of:

- Team Foundation Server
- Project Server

As I understand it, both require SQL Server and Project Server also requires SharePoint server.  Is this right?

We have an existing intranet server and database server.  Can we install TFS, Project Server (and SharePoint Server if needed) on our intranet server and point to our database server for data?  Or, is it a more normal practice to have a dedicated TFS server (with its own SQL) and a dedicated Project server (with it’s own SQL and SharePoint?), and a dedicated SharePoint server?

Answer (score 0):

TFS, SharePoint and Project Server can all be installed onto the same instance of SQL Server if needed. If you want some separation, then you can use different [SQL Server Instances](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx).

The need to break them into separate servers depends entirely upon the load you expecting to give them. If it is only a handful of developers working on a small project, then a one-box solution should be fine, if it's a team a 50 or so working on enterprise scale projects, then you will need to scale your hardware.

The [Wrox Professional TFS 2012](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Team-Foundation-Server-2012.productCd-1118439325.html) book covers this in a lot of detail and is still pretty relevant if you are going to TFS 2013.